# No module named celery using python 3.6 and apache2

Tags: python, django, celery

On my dev machine I installed and configured celery within a django app and it works without issues using python3.5 and the django dev webserver.

When I deploy that app to my production server I get an error "no module named celery". On the production server runs python3.6 with apache2 and mod_wsgi.

On both machines I use django-1.11 and celery-4.1.0 within a virtualenv. I suspect that it's either an issue with python3.6 or with mod_wsgi.

I haven't found any real solution to my issue so I'm trying my luck here :)

Cheers
Michael

Comment: Can you show how you install it in both cases?

Comment: You mean celery? within virtualenv: pip install celery. Everything else was already running, celery is the only newly added module/package

Comment: You use python3.6 - are you sure you have `pip` an alias for pip3? (sorry, I'm not a Python developer, not sure how virtualenv works)

Comment: Virtualenv takes care of the pip version, in this case pip3 to use with python3.6

Answer (score 0):

1. As a sanity check, make sure the celery is actually installed in the virtual environment you use.
2. If you are using virtual environment with mod_wsgi, you may need to setup `python-home=<path_to_your_virtual_env>` in the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive.

Example:

> WSGIDaemonProcess django python-path=/opt/portal/src/ python-home=/opt/venv/django home=/opt/portal/

You can use the comma-separated list if more than one directory is required in python-path

Comment: As I mentioned the django app ran before without any issues, only celery isn't working.

Comment: One possible reason why celery doesn't work is that it is installed in one virtual environment, and Apache is using a different virtual environment or a system python. It is impossible to tell without seeing the configuration but is it possible that you have Django installed in the system interpreter as well, and mod_wsgi is using it?

Comment: There's only one virtualenv and celery is installed only in that. Apache is pointing to that virtualenv. I have, for example, also restframework installed and it works with apache.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. Apparently my virtualenv was pointing to another directory and not to the one apache was using. No idea how this happend. Anyway, after removing and recreating the virtualenv it worked.

Thanks for your help!